# Angular app not opening in IE browser and app opening in Chrome

Tags: javascript, angular

**I was implemented app using Angular 7 version and it was opening in chrome browser and Edge browser but not opening in IE browser.
Can anyone help me on this?**

Comment: Do you mean it does not run on IE?

Comment: Most of the time we get this because there are a lot of commonly used parts of JavaScript that Internet Explorer just doesn’t support. So you can avoid this situation by commenting some imports in 'polyfiles.ts' and do some npm package installations. Please follow the given [link] (https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-and-internet-explorer-5e59bb6fb4e9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular Supports all the IE Versions (11, 10, 9). But to make it possible your need to add  Polyfills. The polyfills are required to run an Angular application on each supported browser.

so if your project have IE 9,10, 11 Versions in the Scope, then you need to add the following code to your polyfills.ts which is available in src folder of your angular Project

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the following on your polyfills.ts?

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
```

In addition, for older browsers such as IE, you should check the required polyfills on their [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support#enabling-polyfills), as you might be using some of the features on that list, yet you might have missed out some polyfills which are not included on the default settings for the polyfills.